# What construction is -데 대한?

Tags: grammar

As I know, 데 means "place", but -데 대한 means "about something or some act". What is the meaning of 데 here? Can it be used with 의한, 관한 or 관련한?

Comment: Although some use -데 대한, it should be 데 대한 (as in 약속을 지키지 못한 **데 대한** 변명) because this 데 equals to 데에; 데 means "place" (곳), "case" (경우), "matter/event/problem" (일), and 것.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked what -데 대한 means. But it actually is '데 대한'; 데 is not a 접미사, it is a 의존명사. Also, keep in mind that 조사 '에' is omitted behind '데'. The original form should be '데에 대한'.

One confusing thing about Korean is that in many cases, you have to tell between 의존명사(dependent noun), 조사(postposition) and 접미사(suffix). Even native Koreans usually don't recognize the difference and mix these, but they sure are different.

But anyways, in this case, 데 is a 의존명사 that means "thing" or "case"; Koreans basically use it everywhere. It would be more helpful to translate the phrase "데 대한" as a whole.

For the next part of your question: is 데 usable with 의한, 관한, or 관련한? Technically yes, since as I wrote above, 데 can be used almost everywhere. In particular, 데 관한/관련한 means the same as 데 대한. But people don't usually use 데 with 의한. They prefer other 의존명사 like 것.